# How to enable IPN in the new paypal view?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Got a brand new business account and since it's a new one - the "switch to classic view" button isn't even there (at least I can't find it under the *More* tab).

How do I turn on Instant Payment Notifications (IPN) in the new layout? I go to tools and I don't even see the IPN option anywhere.

I am sorry if this question sounds stupid, but I've been looking for it for half an hour already.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about PayPal, not computer programming.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to go to Set up the IPN using the direct link :

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-ipn-notify